# Covering shapefile to raster using rasterize in R,return same result

Tags: shapefile, r, rasterization

When i using the blow code to change 'thre' property of shp to raster:

```
r1 <- rasterize(city.1, r,'thre',fun='min')
r2 <- rasterize(city.1, r,'thre',fun='max')
```

here, city.1 is shp, thre is the property that to be transformed, r is the raster layer

I got same result no matter what the `fun` is - any hints on solving the problem?

Comment: The `fun` argument only comes into play when two polygon features overlap each other. Do you have overlapping polygons? You've not shown us your data so we can't tell. It doesn't affect the raster at points where adjacent polygons occupy parts of raster cells - the cell value of the polygon at the centre of the raster cell is always taken.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i am not sure how to upload my data. As you said, the output value of raster is the center vaule of polygon. So no matter what fun is, i always got same result.

Comment: @RuXu How are you opening your `shp` file in `R`? Can you give some information about the vector characterstics i.e. vector class, etc. Also, It would be helpful if you write a MWE ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).